# Where can I find the ProjectAssemblies folder (if it exists) in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

in visual studio 2005 I found it under ...\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies
and ...\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies

Where do these folders exist in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ProjectAssemblies\